# Iptables rules script problem

Tags: iptables, firewall

I found this script online, but there are 2 problems after executing on linux mint:

1. No internet from USB WiFi adapter, only from internal wifi
2. Can not connect to any VPN

What do I have to change inside the script to fix the 2 problems?

https://tech.meetrp.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/firewall.txt

Comment: That's from six years ago. Time moves on (mostly) and there are much better ways to create a firewall ruleset. I would suggest you consider working out what you want (and why), and finding out how to represent that. Typically, "anything outbound but nothing inbound" is a good starting point

Answer (score 3):

1. The script uses the obsolete `ifconfig -s` command to get the names of the interfaces. A new-style name for a USB network interface might be like `enxNNNNNNNNNNNN` where `NNNN...` is the MAC address of the interface. The output of `ifconfig -s` truncates the interface name to 8 characters, and so the generated rule won't match the actual interface name.

You might replace the line

```
INET_FACES=`$IFCONFIG -s | $GREP -vi 'kernel' | $GREP -vi 'iface' | $GREP -v 'lo' | $AWK '{print $1}'`
```

with:

```
INET_FACES=$(/bin/ls /sys/class/net | grep -v lo)
```

2. You'll need to add rules to cover the requirements of the VPN you wish to use. This may involve opening some TCP/UDP ports, allowing some ICMP packets, and/or allowing some IPsec (ESP) or other encapsulation (GRE, L2TP, possibly something else) protocols in and out. The exact ports/protocols you'll need to open will depend on the specific VPN you wish to use. Also, a VPN client will usually create a new virtual network interface on starting up a connection; if the script was executed before the VPN starts, any traffic to/from that virtual interface will fall victim to the default deny-everything rule.

In general, I would not recommend using random firewall scripts from the internet until you've thoroughly read them **and understand what they do**. However, if you want to learn firewalling the hard way, this 6 years old script might be a serviceable starting point.

Comment: Can you recommend a good (and maybe not-so-random) iptables-based firewall script?

Comment: it works now after changing the line. i have the config file for vpn.  udb server port